# std::allocator_traits::construct invokes wrong constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, std-pair, move-constructor

Motivated from Haskell, I tried to implement `std::forward_list` like this:

```
namespace std {
    template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T>>
    class forward_list {
        typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<pair<forward_list<T>,T>> alloc;
        typename allocator_traits<decltype(alloc)>::pointer ptr;
    public:
        // ...
        void push_front(const T &value) {
            auto newPtr = allocator_traits<decltype(alloc)>::allocate(alloc, 1);
            allocator_traits<decltype(alloc)>::construct(alloc, newPtr, move(*this), value);
            ptr = newPtr;
        }
        // ...
    };
}
```

But the `construct` in `push_front` calls copy constructor, rather than move constructor.

I don't understand. `construct` has forwarding references as arguments, so does the constructor of `std::pair`. So the rvalue reference from `std::move` should be delivered intact. So why is this happening?

(I'm sorry if this is a dupe. The searching system of Stack Exchange doesn't cut it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I implemented the move constructor wrongly:

```
forward_list(
    forward_list &&other
) : forward_list(other, other.alloc) {}
```

It must be:

```
forward_list(
    forward_list &&other
) : forward_list(move(other), other.alloc) {}
```